# What is this weird encoding of my username on Meta.Rus?

Tags: bug, profile-page

I joined Russian.se to ask a specific question of translation. I didn't know if my question would be on-topic, so I [asked on its Meta first](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/407/would-this-translation-question-be-welcome) (long story short, it wouldn't be).

I went back today to that meta-question today, to see if there'd been any additional answers or commentary, and I saw this weird string where my username would normally be:

[image: screenshot of weird username]

In case it matters, the specific string is:

> a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae

Which I take to be some kind of GUID or something. In any case, I'd expect to see my normal username "Dan Bron" appear, as it does here on Meta.se and all the other sites where I have accounts.

Some notes:

1. I primarily use the iOS app. I'm not 100% certain I joined Rus.SE and asked this question using it, but it's a good bet.
2. I'm using the iOS app right now to view the question, but I checked and the weird string shows up in mobile Safari and Chrome too.
3. I joined the stack using the normal mechanism, likely on iOS, but either way I just started asking a question and when prompted with "do you want to join this community?", I selected "yes". I did not sign up independently and then link the accounts or anything.
4. I did not delete my account or otherwise interact with the stack since I asked the question and accepted the answer.
5. The gravatar is correct, so the system still apparently "recognizes" me, and the username isn't something like "userXXXX", so I don't think my account has been deleted by mods or CMs or anything without me asking.

What's going on here?

Comment: I fixed up your profiles manually in the meantime. Sorry about the inconvenience!

Comment: @AdamLear Thanks, appreciated!